# HTML button onserverclick event doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to use the onclickserver on ASP.net to do something when the user clicks on a button but when I click the button nothing happens.

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the button:

```
<button id="BttnLead" class="bttnBlck" runat="server" onserverclick="BtnLead_OnClick">Lead</button>
```

And here the event I'm trying to use:

```
  protected void BtnLead_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Thank you.

Comment: try, <asp:Button OnClick="BtnLead_OnClick" ...

Comment: This is Web Forms? Please tag your question appropriately. And why not use an `<asp:Button>`? What happens when you click the button? Do you get a JavaScript error? Does a postback occur?

Comment: Btn_Lead_OnCllick Method are empty ? or it just for the example?

Comment: @ShaiEitan is an example, thank you.

Comment: @DavidJ.E.did you try use <asp:button> like the other guys told you above?

Comment: Yes, thank you all, but it change all the styles, sorry I'm new.

Comment: Use as mentioned above and use skin or Cssclass to give required classes so you maintain the style .

Comment: `<asp:Button id="BttnLead" CssClass="bttnBlck" runat="server" OnClick="BtnLead_OnClick" Text="Lead" />` should be your markup, and it shouldn't change the styling.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the markup or code-behind in your example.  If it's not posting back when you click the button, I think you have something else going on preventing it.  Could you be failing some validation or something on the page client-side that's preventing it?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet it has to do with failed validation somewhere on the page, as @kman pointed out in a comment above. Are you using any `<asp:FieldValidator/>` controls anywhere on the page? If so, and they're not being handled correctly, all you would need to do to cause this button's postback to be triggered is to add the `CausesValidation="false"` property to the `<button>` control. This would have the button avoid the validation code that is (if it's the issue, which I really think it is) inevitably failing and thus never reaching the handler method.

P.S. It should be noted that you do NOT have to use an ASP.NET control (i.e. `<asp:Button>`) and the pure HTML `<button>` control with the `runat="server"` property renders a server side control just the same. However, if you're in the ASP.NET world anyway and you have access to these controls, they do provide some benefit that is nice; but that's a different conversation.